# Is it possible to find Twitter account name from URL of photograph?

Tags: twitter, images

Is it possible to find which Twitter account posted an image from image URL like this: `https://pbs.twimg.com/media/sdsdsdsdsdsd.jpg`?

Answer (score 1):

If the image is public you can reverse search it.

In chrome (IIRC firefox has it too) just right click the image and then "Search google for this image"

**If** you don't have chrome (or FF?) you can save the image locally and go to google [images](https://www.google.com/imghp?gws_rd=ssl) and just drag it over in the box.

Comment: reverse image search doesn't work for all images as you know.

Comment: It doesn't work for images that are not public. Due to privacy settings or other limiting factors. Due to the way twitter handles images you won't be able to find the profile because there are no accessable ties from the image hosting servers to twitter accounts

Comment: It doesn't work for all public images too. Because there is need some time to google index image.